# Binding datepicker and select2 to bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal that uses ajax to populate the content from a db query. However my datepicker and select2 plugin are not working inside of the modal, although they do work on the page. I am relatively new to ajax but I've found some stackoverflow threads suggesting that I need to bind the datepicker and select2 but I am not having any luck.

index.php:
Here is the ajax...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {       
    $('#newCall').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    $.ajax({
      type : 'post',
       url : '../includes/modals/call.php', 
      data :  'id='+ id,
      success : function(data){
         $('.form-data').html(data);
       }
    });
    });
});
```

I have the select2 and datepicker js files included before the ajax.

call.php:

```
<!-- NEW CALL MODAL -->
<div id="newCall" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="form-data"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving $(".datepicker").datepicker(); inside ajax success (see below) fixed the issue for me.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {       
    $('#newCall').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    $.ajax({
      type : 'post',
       url : '../includes/modals/call.php', 
      data :  'id='+ id,
      success : function(data){
         $('.form-data').html(data);
         $(".datepicker").datepicker();
       }
    });
    });
```

});